Point that can be projected onto each side of a convex polygon?
I was reading something about pedal curves and came accross this definition: "Pedal polygons are the polygons obtained by projecting an interior point P on the sides of a convex polygon."
There are papers on pedal polygons such as
this.
However, it always seems to be implicit in these results that the projections of the point P will lie on the sides, and not just on the line generating the sides. It's not at all obvious to me why this should be true?
My question: Given a convex polygon, does there exist a point P on its interior, such that the projections of P onto the lines forming the sides of the polygon actually do lie on the sides?
If not, is there a special name for such points in cases where they do exist? Happy to have references as well.

The projection of a point $P$ lies on segment $AB$ if and only if $P$ lies inside the slab formed by the two lines perpendicular to $AB$, passing through $A$ and $B$.
In the case of a polygon $ABC\dots YZ$, it follows that the projection of a point $P$ lies on all sides $AB, BC, \dots, YZ, ZA$ if and only if $P$ lies in the intersections of all the slabs formed as before from the sides of the polygon.
It is not difficult to construct polygons where no such point exists, see for instance the trapezoid below.

